# Sencha Touch 2. Arrays in JsonP

Tags: arrays, jsonp, sencha-touch-2

I receive Jsonp like:

```
Mycallback([['name1', 'id1', 'price1'], ['name2', 'id2', 'price2']]
```

and want to use it for loading store (throuh Jsonp request all works correctly, but I need to use store.load())

How can I load arrays in my store?

How can I access data in callback function?

Comment: are you imagine this is not a json format?

Comment: JSON validators says it correct JSON. So... normally JSON but in arrays (and I can't change it)

Comment: hmmm, may be... this way you want to have a function Mycallback and call it?

Comment: Yeah, I did it already: declare function in index.html. But I don't know is it good decision or not?

Answer (score 0):

create a model with fields name, id, price and set the store's model property as this model that you have defined then sencha internally stores the data as an array